# Suffix Array Construction Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, implementation, suffix-array

Can Somebody explain me the working of Suffix Array Construction Algorithm given in e-maxx.ru page

I am unable to understand its code

A explanation with a small example can be quite effective

Link : http://e-maxx.ru/algo/suffix_array

Comment: It is not possible to describe this algorithm concisely. I would recommend you reading about it somewhere else.

Comment: I am able to understand the first part of the code the problem occurs only in a single line where i am unable to understand that is **p[--cnt[c[pn[i]]]] = pn[i];** Also why in this looping starts from n-1 to 0 instead of 0 to n-1

Comment: I wouldn't use this implementation at all if I were you. The code is where unclear there. This line actually is an implementation of radix sort.

Comment: Can you suggest me some better source for reading about this

Comment: You can ask the algorithm author - there is a discussion thread at the end of the page you've mentioned.